# VF / HTML markup for RenderAs PDF a specific div that spans 1+ pages in landscape mode

Tags: visualforce, pdf, css

I'm exporting some reports using `renderAs="pdf"` and working fine. I need to add a summary page for those reports(no matter at the beginning or at the end) in **landscape mode**. I used `@page :first{size:landscape;}`  which is some what ok. But since the summary content can't assumed to be in one page I'm looking for apply this to a `<div />`. Is this possible?

```
<div id="content ">
  //repeating content with page breaks and all working fine
</div>

<div id="summary">
  // this content need to be in landscape since more columns
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes its Possible !!
All you need to do is ,add the following css in your style tag

```
 @page landScapeMode
 {
     size:landscape;
 }
#summary
{
    page:landScapeMode;    
}
```

So basically what I have done is I have made use of named page selectors!
Hope this helps !